# fetch API with POST method giving me 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: post, fetch-api, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I'm using a fetch with POST method to get data from an API in my index.html page but am getting 500 status code, can somebody please guide me on what could be wrong in my code

```
<body>
<h1>Flights Finder</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
fetch("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/v1.0", {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'API_KEY',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': {
      'inboundDate': '2019-11-24',
      'cabinClass': 'business',
      'children': '0',
      'infants': '0',
      'country': 'US',
      'currency': 'USD',
      'locale': 'en-US',
      'originPlace': 'SFO-sky',
      'destinationPlace': 'LHR-sky',
      'outboundDate': '2019-11-16',
      'adults': '1'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})

.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 is an internal server error. You should check if no error is being thrown on the server.

Comment: Kwame Opare Asiedu, I am not using any server, the html page is running on my browser locally could that be a problem, I mean do i have to use a server to use POST method

Comment: Then the service you are using (https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/v1.0") is the one throwing the error...
Cos error 500 is a server-side error, not a client-side error

Comment: Pls check that you are sending the right data in the right format to the server

Comment: I'm actually getting the data when fetching through request method in node.js but i don't know why it's throwing error when using fetch method

Comment: Just took a look at the API in question and it seems the `apikey` should be in the body, not the header